# How to generate sql file from Liquibase without DATABASECHANGELOG inserts?

Tags: ant, liquibase

I have the following problem : I need to produce migration file for a database in production. Currently I'm using ant and following ant task :

```
<liquibase:updateDatabase changeLogFile=db.changelog-master.xml" databaseRef="oracle-database"  outputFile="out_ora.sql"  />
```

But my file includes insert statements for DATABASECHANGELOG table. How can I produce output file without this statements ? (I wouldn't like to delete this statements manually or by some script later).

Comment: Can you use contexts to filter out the changesets that contain insert statements? See: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/contexts.html

Comment: But how could i use it ? Insert statements for DATABASECHANGELOG table are generated automatically, after every changeset, so I have no control to mark them with context parameter

Comment: Ahhh, now I understand. You're talking about the INSERT statements that liquibase creates when you generate a SQL file. Short answer is that you don't want to filter these out. They're a very important feature of liquibase, enabling it to properly track the changesets already applied. If you really really really want to remove them, filter them out with a script. In conclusion, my advise is to leave them in.

Comment: Yes, I really really want to remove them. As I've mentioned, i create migration sql file to database which is placed on production system. This database does not contain DATABASECHANGELOG table, because Liquibase has been applied to existing database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-nochangelogupdate

Just add the jar to your classpath and liquibase will not output any databasechangelog SQL

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the insert/update from ChangeSets irrespective of Liquibase Insert/update statements retaining only the Create, Alter scripts.

Define a property with list of classes to be excluded

```
 sqlgenerator.exclude=liquibase.statement.core.InsertOrUpdateStatement,liquibase.statement.core.InsertStatement,liquibase.statement.core.UpdateStatement,liquibase.statement.core.GetNextChangeSetSequenceValueStatement,liquibase.statement.core.MarkChangeSetRanStatement,liquibase.statement.core.RemoveChangeSetRanStatusStatement,liquibase.statement.core.UpdateChangeSetChecksumStatement
```

Implement a SQL Generator class that filters all the SQL statements falls into the class category listed above.

Spring injects the property into the class. Be sure to create the class under the package "liquibase.sqlgenerator.ext".

```
@Component
public class FilteredSQLGenerator extends AbstractSqlGenerator<AbstractSqlStatement> {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(FilteredSQLGenerator.class);

  private static String[] excludeArr = new String[0];

  @Value("${sqlgenerator.exclude}")
  private String exclude;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {

    LOGGER.debug(" Exclude List set to : " + exclude);
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(exclude)) {
      excludeArr = StringUtils.split(exclude, ',');
    }

  }


  @Override
  public ValidationErrors validate(AbstractSqlStatement statement, Database database, SqlGeneratorChain sqlGeneratorChain) {
    return sqlGeneratorChain.validate(statement, database);
  }


  @Override
  public int getPriority() {
    return 1000;
  }

  @Override
  public Sql[] generateSql(AbstractSqlStatement statement, Database database, SqlGeneratorChain sqlGeneratorChain) {

    String clazzName = statement.getClass().getName();

    for (String exclude : excludeArr) {
      if (exclude.equals(clazzName)) {
        return new Sql[0];
      }
    }

    return sqlGeneratorChain.generateSql(statement, database);
  }
}
```

Comment: Kamal,  Is it possible to achieve the task which you mentioned above through Maven ?

Comment: I'm not sure if you have found the solution already. If you can extend the liquibase maven plugin, you should be able to generate them with maven as well